# Alamofire API connection and Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm having an issue with an AlamoFire request to the EatStreet API. I have an API key and I have imported Alamofire correctly.

https://developers.eatstreet.com/endpoint/search

Below is the link to the website where they will create the API URL string for you.

Even with all this I'm still not succeeding

This is the sample string

```
curl -X GET \
 -H 'X-Access-Token: __API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY__' \
 'https://api.eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?latitude=40.718293&longitude=-74.002276&method=pickup&pickup-radius=2'
```

Below is my sample code with my api and Alamofire request. It keeps returning false for the value of result. Any help is appreciated

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

import FirebaseAuth
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let apiToContact = "\\ -H 'X-Access-Token: f6565a0360167144' \\'https://api.eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?latitude=40.718293&longitude=-74.002276&method=pickup&pickup-radius=2'"
    Alamofire.request(apiToContact).validate().responseJSON() { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)

                // Do what you need to with JSON here!
                // The rest is all boiler plate code you'll use for API requests
                print(json)

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }


}


//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Alamofire Docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers), you should send request with header parameters

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "X-Access-Token": "API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY"
]

let url = "https://api.eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?latitude=40.718293&longitude=-74.002276&method=pickup&pickup-radius=2"

Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: @HiDungLing great, please mark as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be like the following. Here the Query parameters are automatically generated and appended to URL. This approach prevents some special character escaping in query params. Try the following

```
 func sendRequest() {
    let headers = ["X-Access-Token":"eatstreetToken"]
    let parameters:[String:Any] = ["latitude":40.718293,"longitude":-74.002276, "method":"pickup","pickup-radius":2]
    let apiToContact = "https://api.eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search"

    let request = Alamofire.request(apiToContact, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers)
    request.validate().responseJSON() { response in
        print(response.response?.url ?? "malformed url")
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
              print(value)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i want the encoding to be json

Comment: doesn't look like what eatstreet returns for that string

Comment: I just tried the above code myself by creating new account on eatstreet developer portal, and the response that was printed on my console is correct